# How do i create a agent/daemon that listens for NSDistributedNotifcations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, daemon

I've created a command line cocoa program which creates an NSDistributedNotification, which other applications send notifications to. How can i keep the program running in an active state so it can still receive NSDistributedNotifications

Comment: You tagged this "daemon", which is the answer, so be more specific.

Comment: The guide given in the answer below seems to warn against using NSDistributedNotifications in favor of UNIX sockets. I am curious as to which one went with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Creating launchd Daemons and Agents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html) on Mac OS X.

Comment: I don't see anything in this guide that mentions NSDistributedNotifications.